# How to set main class in build?

Tags: sbt

Upon `sbt run` I have multiple choices of main class.

I would like to set a main class so I've writen in `build.sbt`:

```
mainClass := Some("aMainClass")
```

But sbt fails with:

```
build.sbt:1: error: not found: value aMainClass
```

I've also tried with `project/Project.scala` file :

```
import sbt._
  class ExecutableProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info)  {
  override def mainClass = Some("aMainClass")
}
```

error :

```
 project/Project.scala:3: not found: type aMainClass
```

How to set the main class in a build?

Answer (score 112):

The main Class must be fully qualified with the package:

```
Compile/mainClass := Some("myPackage.aMainClass")
```

This will work for run and it will set the Main-Class in the Manifest when using the package task. The main class for these tasks can be set separately as in:

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("myPackage.aMainClass")
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("myPackage.anotherMainClass")
```

Note:

```
mainClass := Some("myPackage.aMainClass")
```

does nothing. If you put this in your build file you will receive no warning that it does nothing.

Comment: Note similarly that `mainClass in run := Some("myPackage.aMainClass")` also does nothing.

Comment: And what if the `main` method lives in a class that is not in any package, e.g. in App.class location [...]/src/main/scala/App.class?

Comment: ^^ mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("App")

Answer (score 23):

As far as I know, `sbt` expects here a fully qualified class/object name within your project. For example, if your main class is like this:

```
package prog

object Main extends App {
    // Hic sunt dracones
}
```

then you would have to give your main class like this:

```
mainClass := Some("prog.Main")
```

You get a type error because that type is not simply found.

Comment: Using SBT 0.11.2 I found I had to set the main class in the compile and runtime scopes:  
   
    `mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("prog.Main")`

Answer (score 1):

My sbt version is  sbt 1.5.4 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.11).

And I find `mainClass in (Compile, run) :=Some("Hello")`  doesn't work in my build.sbt.

I finally find the offical example for 1.x version in [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def-Examples.html)

```
// set the main class for packaging the main jar
// 'run' will still auto-detect and prompt
// change Compile to Test to set it for the test jar
Compile / packageBin / mainClass := Some("myproject.MyMain"),

// set the main class for the main 'run' task
// change Compile to Test to set it for 'test:run'
Compile / run / mainClass := Some("myproject.MyMain"),
```

you can add it to your settings. It works for me.

But I don't know how to integrate those commands into one.

Comment: And [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674615/sbt-start-a-command-line-run-of-the-main-class-of-a-non-default-project) also works  in interactive mode.