# SBT: Start a command line 'run' of the main class of a non-default project

Tags: scala, sbt

I am starting to use [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) build my Scala code (and handle dependencies). As far as I know if I use

```
$ sbt run <args>
```

on the command line this will run the main class of the main project.

Is it possible to 'run' within any other project from the command line, i.e. not in the interactive session mode? (I'm thinking about something that might look like `$ sbt project <proj> run <args>` or whatever...)

What I would do in interactive mode is this:

```
$ sbt
> project <projectname>
> run <args>
```

This seems to be straightforward enough, but I can not find any documentation describing this behavior. Hints would be much appreciated...

Comment: how to use specify the main project?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You simply have to quote each command (as in the second example [on this page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Running)), so in your case it would be:

```
$ sbt "project foo" "run arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: Darn, I was so close :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 48):

`$ sbt foo/run arg1 arg2` also work

Comment: I think that it is more native way than doubling command in most voted answer

Answer (score 22):

This works: `sbt "runMain com.example.Hello arg1"` or `sbt "run-main com.example.Hello arg1"`.

See here for reference: https://blog.ssanj.net/posts/2016-03-02-how-to-run-a-specific-main-class-with-parameters-through-sbt.html

Answer (score 10):

Worked for me:

```
$ sbt "run someNumber"
```

Also this may be of some help:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n = args(0).toInt
}
```