# Passing Command-Line Arguments to SBT for Setting TypeSafe Config Key-Value

Tags: scala, sbt

Given the following "Main" app:

```
package net

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Main extends App {
    override def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val x = ConfigFactory.load().getString("app.bar")
        println(s"x: $x")
    }
}
```

and `application.conf`:

```
app {
    bar = ${?BAR}
}
```

I could pass in the command-line argument via:

```
$sbt test:run -DBAR=bippy
[info] Set current project to typesafe_config_env_var 
    (in build file:.../typesafe_config_env_var/)
[info] Running net.Main 
x: bippy
```

I wrote this simple example to try to reproduce a [problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/3QYX4Mcc9Do) resolving a command-line argument. However, as the output above shows, this test worked successfully.

Is this the standard way of passing command-line arguments in sbt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SBT: Start a command line 'run' of the main class of a non-default project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674615/sbt-start-a-command-line-run-of-the-main-class-of-a-non-default-project)

Comment: But I don't know how to set `app.bar` to a value based via a `-Dkey=value` command-line argument. Is it possible with that approach, @ChrisMartin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with standard. AFAIK, this is the "standard" way of passing arguments:

```
$ sbt "run --bippy"
```

Your example is basically using a feature from the typesafe config that binds environment variables to `application.conf` definitions. [Here's a tutorial](http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/02/leveraging-typesafes-config-library-across-environments/) for that.

Comment: Can I use this approach to set `app.bar` per my `application.conf`? If so, can you please show me?

Comment: Kevin, your code is explicitly reading from the `application.conf`. If you want to test for the presence of `--bippy`, then you'll have to peek `args`, like, `if (args.exists(_ == "--blippy")) doStuff`.

Comment: But, isn't my above example showing that, although I'm reading from the typesafe config, `app.bar` is being set based on a command-line argument,   namely `$sbt test:run -DBAR=bippy` assigning `app.bar` to `bippy`?

Comment: `-DBAR=bippy` is setting the environment variable `BAR` to `bippy`, nothing else. Then, in `application.conf`, the line `bar = ${?BAR}` sets the `app.bar` to whatever value the environment variable `BAR` is set to. It might seem that you're passing arguments when in fact you're just doing the equivalent to `export BAR=bippy && sbt test:run`.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why an environment variable might be ignored from the command line?

Comment: I appreciate the tutorial link and your help. So, if I'm trying to override `http { port = ${?HTTP_PORT} }` within the `sbt test:run` command. I tried `sbt test:run -Dhttp.port=8081`, but I got a `ConfigException$Missing`.

Comment: You should do `sbt test:run -DHTTP_PORT=8081`. Be aware that the environment variable is not `http.port` (this is the configuration parameter path), but the one given by `${?HTTP_PORT}`. If this is helping, I would be most appreciated if you could accept the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. Lastly, if I have another value, let's say `http.foo= ${?FOO}`. I tried `sbt test:run -DHTTP_PORT=8081 -DFOO=FOO`, but got a `ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution` exception when looking for `FOO`'s value.