# Is there a way to automatically package multiple main classes in the same SBT project with sbt-onejar?

Tags: scala, sbt, onejar

I have an **SBT** project that contains multiple classes with `main`, i.e. `MyClass extends App`. **One-jar** works fine when there is only one such class. If it finds multiple classes it prompts me to choose which one I want to package:

```
> one-jar

Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

 [1] com.smth.AppOne
 [2] com.smth.AppTwo

Enter number:
```

I'd like to configure one-jar to automatically package all main classes. In [documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) it defines default main class as `mainClass in run in Compile`, so it looks like it expects only one value.

If this is not possible I'm curious why not. :)

For now I can only think of some hacks like creating a surrogate project for each jar or setting a `mainClass` in SBT each time before calling `one-jar` (multiple times per build). These approaches obviously have their deficiencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about SBT or onejar plugin. When you pack your project into the jar file, both main classes would be packed. [JAR File specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) defines that you can have as many classes with `main()` method as you want, but there should be only one class with `main()` method defined in `Main-Class` attribute per JAR

Comment: Yep, so what I'm trying to achieve is for onejar to create one `*.jar` file per each class with `main()` that it finds in my src. It might happen that jars will be identical, but `Main-class` attr will be set to a different value in each one. Onejar can clearly discover these candidates. All I want is for onejar to package each one in a separate jar.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov There is a task `discoveredMainClasses in Compile`, make your custom task which depends on it and for each main class run onejar

Comment: Thanks @Alexlv, I'll try that. I was hoping to avoid creating custom tasks :).

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov If you don't want to make a custom task, then do a simple command. You can avoid task dependency and call execute other task with `Project.runTask`

Answer (score 3):

Use the following to set up the default main class:

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.smth.AppOne")
```

Source: [This stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6467423/1287856)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

```
mainClass in oneJar := Some("com.acme.Woozler")
```

Try to add

```
mainClass in oneJar := Some("com.smth.AppOne")
```

in you configuration

Comment: This does not solve the problem at least because I have to manually specify all class names. Furthermore I think it will just overwrite the setting instead of adding to a Seq of values (I didn't try though).

Answer (score 0):

I would try sbt multi-project builds. You should be able to set a main class per project.