# SBT won't pick the specified mainClass

Tags: scala, sbt

I wrote this scala code

```
package com.abhi

import java.io.File

object Main1 {
    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
        println("Main1 Hello World")
    }
}

object Main2 {
    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
        println("Main2 Hello World")
    }
}
```

and this built.sbt file

```
name := "Foo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"   
)

mainClass:= Some("com.abhi.Main1")
```

But when I run `sbt run` it still says

```
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list

Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

 [1] com.abhi.Main1
 [2] com.abhi.Main2

Enter number:
```

Why is it still asking me for which class to chose? The main class to choose was already specified in the build.sb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer to [How to set main class in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467423/how-to-set-main-class-in-build)

You'll need something like:

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.abhi.Main1")
```