# Get jar system path in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get system path, where jar is located in run time.

Below code works in REPL but, it fails if I assemble jar using sbt,

```
object tboj {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def getCurrentDirectory = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath
    val pwd = getCurrentDirectory
    println(pwd)
  }
}
```

SBT error as below,

> > run
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
> >             at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
> >     [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
> >     [error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
> >     [error] Total time: 0 s, completed 13 Apr, 2016 5:15:40 PM

Comment: the error has nothing to do with the implementation of `main` - java can't _find_ the main function because the jar does not include the main-class attribute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467423/how-to-set-main-class-in-build for solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find location of Jar using Class Name then use following way -

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
classOf[FileSystem].getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath())
```

If you have instance, then use following way -

```
new ListBuffer[String]().getClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

That will be `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Worked for me for resolving native libs within my project.

Comment: That will get the user's home directory, which is not the same as the directory that the JAR file is located in of the running application.

Comment: Nope, per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html it's a user working directory, not a user home.

Comment: But that's still not what the OP is asking for, which is the location where the JAR of the running application is.

Answer (score 0):

try `println(getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation)`