# How to run a Scala class that's in a package from the command line

Tags: scala

I have a Scala project that I want to run from the command line. However, this is within a package so if I try to run the class `Main`(which contains a `main` method) I get:

```
error: illegal start of definition
package mypackage
```

Any idea how to run `Main` from the command line while still keeping the package?

Comment: Are you using `sbt`? I you run `sbt run` does it work?

Comment: `sbt run` works but doesn't open a console for the user. The `Main` class is supposed to open a user console.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't open a console for the user"?

Comment: I want to prompt the user for input. When I run the project with `sbt` this doesn't happen.

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467423/how-to-set-main-class-in-build

Comment: http://scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Comment: @mfirry I added `mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("mypackage.Main")

mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("mypackage.Main")` to my code but this has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sbt run` works as you say, `sbt console` is what you are looking for.

Once you are in the sbt console, execute your main method by typing

```
mypackage.Main.main()
```

Comment: If I run `mypackage.Main.main(Array.empty)` then I don't get a user console.

Comment: Is there an infinite loop in your main function?

Comment: Yes, there is one which asks for user input.

Comment: How exactly do you open the user console?

Comment: `while(true) {
    println("something")
    /*some other code*/
    scanner.nextLine()
   /*some other code*/
}`

Comment: Here's an example how you can use Scanner to read input. Note that you have to press return twice when you give the input in sbt console. https://i.imgur.com/RhXDF7N.png Perhaps your Scanner is not reading the input from System.in?

Answer (score 0):

First `sbt` and when you're in the console mode (i.e. right after you hit enter) `runMain Main`.

That always worked for me.

Comment: If I do that, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main`(the class is not seen even though it exists).

Comment: The same happens for `runMain mypackage.Main`? If you do `sbt` then `compile` do you get a success message?