# AWS EMR Spark Cluster - Steps with Scala fat JAR, can't find MainClass

Tags: scala, jar, executable-jar, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have a fat jar, written in Scala, packaged by sbt.  I need to use it in a Spark cluster in AWS EMR.

It functions fine if I manually spin up the cluster, copy the jar to the master and run a spark-submit job using a command like this...

```
spark-submit --class org.company.platform.package.SparkSubmit --name platform ./platform-assembly-0.1.0.jar arg0 arg1 arg2
```

But...  if I try to add it as a step to the EMR cluster, it fails.  The log to stderr looks like this...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.SparkSubmit
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

The relevant settings in my build.sbt look like this...

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "platform",
    version := "0.1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.5",
    organization := "org.company",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("package/SparkSubmit")
  )
```

The corresponding file with my MainClass looks like...

```
package org.company.platform.package

object SparkSubmit {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

In EMR Console...  in the "Add Step" dialogue...  next to the "Arguments" box, it says...

*"These are passed to the main function in the JAR. If the JAR does not specify a main class in its manifest file you can **specify another class name as the first argument**."*

I'd think because I DO specify a main class in the build.sbt, I'd be fine...  but it fails and doesn't log anything about the failure.  If I try to specify the main class as the first arg, it logs the failure I posted above.

I think it's probably a formatting problem, but I can't sort out how to fix it, and no examples turn up.  I've tried submitting the following as args in the "Add Step" dialog...

```
arg0 arg1 arg2
package.SparkSubmit arg0 arg1 arg2
package/SparkSubmit arg0 arg1 arg2
org.company.platform.package.SparkSubmit arg0 arg1 arg2
```

A few others too, but nothing works.

Version info...
EMR 4.3
Spark 1.6
Scala 2.10
sbt 0.13.9

Any ideas what dumb mistake I'm making that's not letting EMR/Spark find my main class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - got this to "work" by making problems 1-6 go away, but then the cluster just kind of sat there saying it was "running" the first step, but it never finished.  I had mistakenly set step type to "custom jar" instead of "spark application".  After switching that, I think only the fix for "problem 1" was relevant, and that alone may have fixed my problem.  I had to back out the fixes to problems 2, 3 and 5 below to get it working with "spark application" steps, and I suspect I can back out the rest of them as well.  **END EDIT**

I spent a long time getting this to work.  I'll post the errors and fixes sequentially in case it's useful for someone else down the road.

**Problem 1**

no matter what I passed in as the first arg to try and point to the MainClass...  I got the same error.  The problem was in my build.sbt.  I (wrongly) thought organization and name in root were enough to provide the package prefix.

I changed mainClass in build.sbt to match my declared package at the top of the file with my SparkSubmit object in it...

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("org.company.platform.package.SparkSubmit")
```

then in the "Add Step" dialog, I just passed in the args, no class designation...  so just "arg0 arg1 arg2".

Interesting reference if you want to set different MainClass's in the manifest vs. the run...  [How to set main class in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467423/how-to-set-main-class-in-build)

**Problem 2**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

I found this reference...  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

I didn't know which one to use, but since EMR uses Yarn, I set it to "yarn".  **This was wrong.**  (leaving it in as a record of the subsequent error it generated)  In SparkSubmit.main(), I set master URL like this...

```
val conf = 
  new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("yarn")
  .setAppName("platform")
```

**Problem 3**

The master URL error went away, and now this was my error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
```

In my build.sbt...  I had spark-core and spark-sql listed as "provided" in libraryDependencies...  I have no idea why this doesn't work as an EMR Step since the cluster has Spark loaded...  but I removed that and changed it to...

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0", // % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0", //  % "provided",
  ...
)
```

Note - after removing "provided" I got a new error, but changing the versions of spark-core and spark-sql to 1.6.0 to match EMR 4.3 made that go away.

Problem solved...  new one created!

**Problem 4**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
```

The answer was here...  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#when-using-jarjar-onejar-assembly-or-any-jar-bundler

Basically, Akka's reference.conf was getting lost.  My build.sbt mergeStrategy looked like this...

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

I modified it to look like this instead...

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
   {
    case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

**Problem 5**

I guess "yarn" wasn't the right choice in problem 2.  I got this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'yarn'
```

I changed the url to "local[2]"...

```
val conf = 
  new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[2]")
  .setAppName("starling_for_mongo")
```

No valid reason for that value...  not sure how many threads I actually need...  or where this is even applied...  is it in the master, or in some vm somewhere...  i'm not sure.  Need to understand this more, but I just copied what was here, because... uh...  why not?  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html#spark-properties

Need to understand what's being set here.

**Problem 6**

Next came a lot of Serialization errors.  I don't understand why, when all this code ran without any problems as a manual spark-submit or in spark-shell.  I fixed it by essentially going through and making every class extend Serializable.

**The End**

That was my journey getting a working jar written in scala and compiled with sbt to function as a step in an EMR spark cluster.  I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: I use SBT (Scala Build Tool) for everything, and that has a REPL.  `sbt console`

Comment: AWS EMR does not have sbt by default right? I mean wouldn't we have to configure it with their configuration of scala spark? Any ideas on that?

Comment: Why not just use EMR's Spark, and use spark-shell as the Scala REPL?  Don't really understand what you're trying to do though.

Comment: There is a jar which is the output of `sbt package` on local system and it needs to be run with spark-submit on the cluster(where it can reach with scp), also it is not obvious how to add the step in AWS EMR with the jar