# ClassNotFoundException when adding package at the first line of the main file

Tags: java, scala, sbt, package

I am using `sbt package` to create a `.jar` file and submit to `spark-submit`

if I use

```
package mygraph
import mygraph._
object GApp {
    def main ...
```

Then it throws `ClassNotFoundException: GApp`, but if I delete the first line and change to

```
import mygraph._
object GApp {
    def main ...
```

then it can work, why?

My `build.sbt` is as follows

```
name := "ag"

version := "1.0"

artifactName := { (sv, md, art) => "g.jar" }

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

assemblyJarName in assembly := "G.jar"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "2.0.1" % "provided",
  "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.0.0-M2" % "provided"
)
```

Comment: can you post your sbt definition as well?

Comment: @prayagupd do you mean `build.sbt`? I added my `build.sbt` just now

Comment: Ok, you might want to add `mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("mygraph.GApp")` so that jar knows which main to run. I believe you fire `java -jar G.jar` to run the jar. Or else you can do `java -cp G.jar mygraph.GApp` - See [How to set main class in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198743/432903)

Comment: Which sbt version are you using? And please try upgrading the Scala version

Comment: @RamanMishra So what you mean is that `package` should not affect the use of the program?

Comment: @prayagupd thanks! I think this tutorial would help me