# sbt-assembly - can not find main class in jar

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I have a project where I am trying to create a fat jar using the sbt-assembly plugin. When I attempt to run my main class from the jar using the `java -jar` command, I get the error message: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.gordon.timeshare.apps.TimeShareLauncher`.

I only have one main class in my project (I use the `extends App` syntax to accomplish this), so I do not specify the path to the main class explicitly, although I have tried that and it did not help.

Below are all the settings I have in my `build.sbt` file.

```scala
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.gordon.timeshare.apps"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.5"

lazy val app = (project in file("app"))
  .settings(
    assembly / mainClass := Some("com.gordon.timeshare.apps.TimeShareLauncher"),
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "TimeShareLauncher.jar"
  )

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I have also tried other strategies like `deduplicate`, but that would give me an error when trying to make the .jar.

Additionally, when making the .jar, I get a warning:

```
[warn] Could not create directory C:\Users\dgord\workspace\new-timeshare\timeshare\target\streams\_global\assembly\_global\streams\assembly\88fbe735ce5abc6987fbc59b072404628cdc94b4_a99f2fe2a42747ed9809d4f62f51a9e1b336dde8_da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709\META-INF\versions\9: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\dgord\workspace\new-timeshare\timeshare\target\streams\_global\assembly\_global\streams\assembly\88fbe735ce5abc6987fbc59b072404628cdc94b4_a99f2fe2a42747ed9809d4f62f51a9e1b336dde8_da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709\META-INF\versions\9
```

And in case you want to know what my main class looks like:

```scala
package com.gordon.timeshare.apps

object TimeShareLauncher extends App
```

- sbt: 1.4.7 (also tried 1.5.5)
- sbt-assembly: 1.1.0
- scala 2.13.5

I have also tried this on WSL and had the same result.

Comment: Your error says it's looking for `com.gordon.apps.TimeShareLauncher` but your class is `com.gordon.timeshare.apps.TimeShareLauncher`

Comment: @GaëlJ fixed that, I still have the same issue. I've updated what my build file looks like.

Comment: @DanGordon Could you unzip the content of the fat jar and make sure that the following holds. 1. there is file `com/gordon/timeshare/apps/TimeShareLauncher.class`. 2. There is a file `META-INF/Manifest.txt` with content `Main-Class: com.gordon.timeshare.apps.TimeShareLauncher`

Comment: Dont forget to `reload` the build.sbt file after modification

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc the manifest file has `Main-Class: com.gordon.timeshare.apps.TimeShareLauncher`, however the class does not appear to be in the .jar, which makes sense that it's not finding it. I just don't understand why it's not being added to the .jar.

Comment: Answered my own question below. The issue was with `lazy val app = (project in file("app"))`. Should have been `lazy val app = (project in file("."))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set main class in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467423/how-to-set-main-class-in-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `lazy val app = (project in file("app"))`. Assuming a single module project with no module named `app`, sbt-assembly will create a directory named `app` and attempt to stuff the build in there. However, since the main class is not in the `app` bundle, the class will not be added to the jar file.

The correct way to do this is:

`lazy val app = (project in file("."))`, which specifies the current directory as the one to look for the main class. So this was not really an issue with knowing how to use the `sbt-assembly` plugin, but a more general issue with specifying projects in an sbt build.

Comment: But then the structure of the project needs to be changed