# Scala JAR file build with SBT issue: [error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, sbt

I have encountered with this error while building Scala JAR file, please help me.

build.sbt file:

```
cat > databricks_jar_test/build.sbt << EOF
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.14"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.nm.udf"

lazy val udfDecrypt = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "udfDecrypt"
  )
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library
libraryDependencies += "com.macasaet.fernet" % "fernet-java8" % "1.5.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "3.1.2"
```

Scala file

```
cat > databricks_jar_test/src/main/scala/udfDecrypt.scala << EOF
package com.nm.udf;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import com.macasaet.fernet.{Key, StringValidator, Token};
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import java.time.{Duration, Instant};

class Validator extends StringValidator {
    override def getTimeToLive() : java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount = {
      Duration.ofSeconds(Instant.MAX.getEpochSecond());
    }
  }

class udfDecrypt extends UDF {
    def evaluate(inputVal: String, sparkKey : String): String = {
      if( inputVal != null && inputVal!="" ) {
        val keys: Key = new Key(sparkKey)
        val token = Token.fromString(inputVal)
        val validator = new Validator() {}
        val payload = token.validateAndDecrypt(keys, validator)
        payload
      } else return inputVal
    }
  }
```

```
cd databricks_jar_test/
sbt compile
```

```
cd databricks_jar_test/
sbt "run Hello World\!"
# Hello, World!
```

> ### [error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
> [error]  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
> [error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last Compile / bgRun' for the full output
> [error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
> [error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jun 1, 2023, 3:06:00 PM
>
> CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-11-2a66b8e4a500> in <cell line: 1>()
> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'cd databricks_jar_test/\nsbt "run Hello World\!"\n# Hello, World! \n')
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_shell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
> 332     if line and not cell:
> 333       cell = ' '
> 334     return super().run_cell_magic(magic_name, line, cell)
> 335
> 336
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
> 2471             with self.builtin_trap:
> 2472                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
> 2473                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
> 2474             return result
> 2475
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
> 140             else:
> 141                 line = script
> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
> 143
> 144         # write a basic docstring:
>
> <decorator-gen-103> in shebang(self, line, cell)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
> 185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
> 186     def magic_deco(arg):
> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
> 188
> 189         if callable(arg):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
> 243             sys.stderr.flush()
> 244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
> 246
> 247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):
>
> CalledProcessError: Command 'b'cd databricks_jar_test/\nsbt "run Hello World\!"\n# Hello, World! \n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.

This is for the encryption. I have tried in Databricks and Colab, same problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is true that there's no main class and thus you cannot run this code like this. This code looks like a library that would be used by some other project.

Comment: I want to use as in this tutorial:
https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/enforcing-column-level-encryption.html

Comment: Okay, so you don't need to run the JAR yourself. You need to package this Scala code to a JAR. Search for "SBT package jar" on your search engine, it should give you some directions and solutions.

Comment: Basically `sbt package` should be enough in your case. Look at /questions/20938177/create-standalone-jar-using-sbt for instance.

Comment: You need to specify the main class in sbt https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198743/5122436 to run it via java after build. But commonly `sbt run`can find main classes automatically.